# Change element position on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a one page / scroll site with 6 slides of the height of the window viewport.

On slide number 2 I have a centered box with absolute position of 200x200 pixel.

when i scroll on that slide i would like to change the position from absolute to fixed and finally when i arrive to slide 4 i would like to change the position back to absolute.

The problem is that when i switch back the element position to absolute at the end of the scroll the box disappears back up on slide number 2.

I don't know if it's clear what I'm trying to explain - but the thing is that i would like the element centered while scrolling different backgrounds.

Comment: can you put this centered box outside the slides?

Comment: Yes of course, i'm trying to find the cleaner solution without any jquery madness. so the idea was just to add and remove css classes on scroll rules...

Comment: the problem is when you scroll past section 4, when you change position from fixed back to absolute, you need to adjust top position of this box, because if not it will jump back to its original position.